# Table creation with minimum records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to create a conditional table in MYSQL? for example I want to create table which should have minimum two records or else records should not be added into table. Consider example like- A band should have at least two members so there should be minimum two records in the table

Comment: I think this is a wrong-headed way of thinking about relational data

Comment: Do you want to create a seperate table for each band?

Comment: Pity the poor solo artist who never gets a gig.

Comment: Open a transaction, insert rows, check the count and rollback when it's less than two, otherwise commit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It won't work how you are saying it.  However you could create table,  add the rows based on your requirements and do a check and drop table if the row count is below two.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ....;
INSERT INTO mytable (...);
INSERT INTO mytable (...);
```

and save it as a script.